# Handling NULL = NULL comparisons in Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a problem with `NULL = NULL` returning `NULL`. I want it to return `True`. After a bit of research I found a line that I thought would work..

`set ansi_nulls off`

I quickly learned that Access doesn't recognize it. So here I am attempting to do nested conditions in Access and it's a complete nightmare.

Is there an easier way to handle this?

Comment: Can you post an example of the conditional you are struggling with? I can't imagine how adding a check for `NULL` would make one much more complicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're doing a large amount of "equal or both null" comparisons, there are multiple solutions:

1. If you're OK with `0 = Null` resulting to true when comparing numbers, or `"" = Null` resulting to true when comparing strings, you can use:

   `If Nz(Value1) = Nz(Value2) Then`

This replaces all Nulls with `0` or `""` dependent on the input type.

Consequences: `Nz(Null) = Nz(Null)` → `True`, `0 = Nz(Null)` → `True`, `"" = Nz(Null)` → `True`, `1 = Nz(Null)` → `False`, `"a" = Nz(Null)` → `False`

2. Create a user-defined function to do the comparison for you

The function:

```
Public Function CompareWithNulls(Value1 As Variant, Value2 As Variant) As Boolean
    If IsNull(Value1) And IsNull(Value2) Then
        CompareWithNulls = True
    Else
        CompareWithNulls = Value1 = Value2
    End If
End Function
```

The use of the function:

`If CompareWithNulls(Value1, Value2) Then`

Comment: I wasn't aware that you could use `If Nz(Value1) = Nz(Value2) Then` but that works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: In my case, using Access 2016, the function throws an error if one of the values is null and is compared to a string. I solved it by adding an `ElseIf` as second check to your function for that case: `ElseIf IsNull(Value1) Or IsNull(Value2) Then
        CompareWithNulls = False        Else `

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `And` keyword to test multiple conditions without nesting:

```
If IsNull(Value1) And IsNull(Value2) Then
```

You could create a method to compare two variables with a null check and then each IF only needs to call this function instead of the usual `=`

Comment: The problem is that I have a fairly large condition which includes values that will never be NULL. As an example... `If streetVal = addressVal AND suiteVal = unitVal THEN` where `suiteVal` and `unitVal` could be NULL, but `streetVal` and `addressVal` never will be.

Comment: Don't add a `NULL` check for the values that could never be `NULL`. But, there's no way around not checking for `NULL` when required.